# Retain cell formatting after data refresh in Power Query Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I want to retain the column width and cell formatting whenever I refresh data in Power Query.

Data formatting under **Table Tools > Design > External Table Data > Properties> unchecking "Adjust column width"** does not work. Even after checking both **"Preserve cell formatting"** and **"Preserve column sort/filter/layout"**

Any work around?

Comment: Uncheck these 3 options in Properties.